# Trying to get the night difference through MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this problem with my Query where I'm getting an excess data when users forgot to time out  example

Time in is **October 02, 2023 02:00:00 PM** and Time out is **October 03, 2023 01:50:00 PM** and the Shift in is **October 02, 2023 02:00:00 PM** and Shift out is   **October 03, 2023 12:00:00 AM**
I'm getting an excess of 6 hours instead of the result of 2 hours only.

```
SELECT
namee,
SUM(
CASE
WHEN STR_TO_DATE(time_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p') >= 
CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 22:00:00') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(time_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p') <= 
CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 06:00:00') 
THEN GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, STR_TO_DATE(time_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p'), 
STR_TO_DATE(time_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), 0)
WHEN STR_TO_DATE(time_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p') >= 
CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 22:00:00') 
THEN GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, STR_TO_DATE(time_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p'),
CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 06:00:00')), 0)
WHEN STR_TO_DATE(time_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p') <= 
CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 06:00:00') 
THEN GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 22:00:00'), 
STR_TO_DATE(time_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), 0)
ELSE GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_in, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 22:00:00'), 
CONCAT(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(shift_out, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')), ' 06:00:00')), 0)
END
AS night_differential_hours
FROM
fingerclock
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(time_in, '%M %d, %Y') BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2023-10-10'
GROUP BY namee;
```

This is my current Query getting the rest night diff. just having a problem when there's someone forgot to time out

Here's my example data and query.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ef6d9/3

**EDIT:**  Night diff Starts with (start) 22:00:00 to (ends) 06:00:00

Comment: You should start by using a suitable data type for your [datetime values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). You current string format cannot be indexed in a meaningful way, meaning performance will get worse as the table grows. Refencing employees by a unique identifier, instead of a string `namee` would probably be a good idea. Also, it seems likely that shifts are common to multiple people and should be moved to their own table.

Comment: It is not clear what you are expecting. The entire night period (2023-10-08 22:00:00 - 2023-10-09 06:00:00) falls within the time_in/time_out (2023-10-08 14:00:00 - 2023-10-09 13:50:00), which gives an overlap of 8 hours. What do you think it should be? Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77249134/edit) with sample data and desired output.